# Django filter bunch of latest entries in models

Tags: python, django

My problem is I'm save all entries in django model but now I want filter these all entries on my view.

I'm trying

```
delBoySale.objects.latest('timeStamp')
```

It return only single entry but I want all entries that are save last.
What I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the slice syntax to get a number of objects:

```
delBoySale.objects.all().order_by('-timeStamp')[:10]
```

This will return ten last saved instances.

To get the instances created in the last hour use filter by `timeStamp` field:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

hour_ago = now() - timedelta(hours=1)
delBoySale.objects.filter(timeStamp__gt=hour_ago).order_by('-timeStamp')
```

Comment: yeah but I don't know how many entries save last time. so is this possible.

Comment: What do you mean be `last time`?  Anyway see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'gte' expression:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#gte

if 'timeStamp' is DateTimeField:

```
last_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
```

if 'timeStamp' is IntegerField:

```
last_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4)
last_date = int(last_date.strftime("%s"))
```

and filter:

```
delBoySale.objects.filter(timeStamp__gte=last_date)
```